# Where is "xcopy" usually located on a development machine?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I have a build process that needs to use xcopy.  I am getting an error, and I want to make sure that it is finding the command ok.

But google is not helpful when searching for where xcopy would be located on my (or my build) machine.

**What is the file path to XCOPY?**

Comment: Protip: use the `where` command to find out where a command or program is located, as in `where xcopy`.

Comment: Also, what error message are you getting?

Comment: @Dai - I am getting the helpful error "Invalid Path".  When I run the command manually after the build is over it works great.  I can only conclude that one of my folders is not there when I try to run the command (though they should both be there).

Comment: I've noticed recently that pre-/post- build steps in VS ignore the PATH and require you to fully qualify every command and/or program.  I'm assuming this may apply to MSBuild as well.  If that's where you're seeing the problem, it would be helpful if you included that in the question (and added the appropriate tags).

Comment: I don't think xcopy really falls under "general computing hardware and software". The opening sentence of this question makes it pretty apparent that this is a tool being used for programming: "I have a build process that needs to use xcopy."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually `%WINDIR%\system32` e.g. `C:\Windows\system32`.

Be aware that on a 64-bit machine, there's some magic going on with the result that what appears to be `C:\Windows\system32` is actually `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.  However for your purposes I don't believe this should matter.

Answer (score 2):

`xcopy.exe` is located under `C:\Windows\system32\xcopy.exe`. There also exists a 32-bit version under `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\xcopy.exe` if you're running an x64 version of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

The following command line show where the `xcopy.exe` file is located so it is equivalent to `where xcopy.exe` command, but it works in any Windows version:

```
for %a in (xcopy.exe) do @echo %~$path:a
```

Answer (score -1):

If you really want it to be accurate, you should use the same method Windows uses to load an executable.

[Where is a 3rd-party utility including source](http://www.flounder.com/whereis.htm), that has an excellent explanation of how Windows locates an executable, dll, etc. It also matters whether you run it via ShellExec or CreateProcess

Comment: where is a windows built in, for a while now.

Comment: I know Windows has had where since Vista/2003 server, but the web page explains exactly how it works. Lots of people still use an older version of Windows that does not include where, but I was emphasizing the documentation on web page that explains how do do this reliably.